# Redirect domain and all the subdomains to a certain sub domain

Tags: nginx, redirect, cname-record, redirection, a-record

I am building a site for the alumni association of my school. I have bought a domain `myschool.com` from `GoDaddy`. In GoDaddy, I have customised `DigitalOcean` as name servers.

I would like to customise DNS of DigitalOcean such that everything related to the domain `myschool.com` can be redirected to `alumni.myschool.com`. Precisely, all the follows can be fulfilled:

- If one enters `alumni.myschool.com` or `www.alumni.myschool.com` in a browser, I want the URL to become `alumni.myschool.com`, and the browser shows our site of the association in my server IP `178.62.87.73`.
- If one enters a wrong subdomain, for example `abc.myschool.com` in a browser, I want the URL to still become `alumni.myschool.com`, and the browser shows our site of the association in my server IP `178.62.87.73`.
- If one just enters the domain, i.e., `www.myschool.com` or `www.myschool.com` in a browser, I want the URL to still become `alumni.myschool.com`, and the browser shows our site of the association in my server IP `178.62.87.73`.

Because of the jet lag and DNS cache issue, it is hard to try and test a setup; it is hard to say if it is a wrong setup or just need to wait.

So could anyone give me a full list of records (A, CNAME...) to realise this?

**Edit 2:**

Following the first answer, I have added the 4 A records with the `.`, and they become

```
@         IN  A   178.62.87.73
alumni    IN  A   178.62.87.73
*         IN  A   178.62.87.73
*.alumni  IN  A   178.62.87.73
```

I have added the following server block in my server:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name myschool.com *.myschool.com;
        return 301 $scheme://alumni.myschool.com$requrest_uri;
}
```

And the server for `alumni.myschool.com` remains the same:

```
server {
        ...
        server_name alumni.myschool.com;
        ...
}
```

The result is that `myschool.com`, `www.myschool.com`, `abc.myschool.com`, `www.abc.myschool.com` and `www.alumni.myschool.com` can all be successfully redirected to `alumni.myschool.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most important thing to note is that the actual redirection that you describe will not be done in DNS.

You could do something like this (minimally):

```
example.com.         IN  A   178.62.87.73
*.example.com.       IN  A   178.62.87.73
```

However, not having an explicit record for the actual name you intend to use is not all that clear to fellow human beings.

For clarity more than anything else, you may want to add:

```
alumni.example.com.    IN  A   178.62.87.73
*.alumni.example.com.  IN  A   178.62.87.73
```

(That first record alone will end the scope where the wildcard immediately under the zone apex applies.)

What will actually get you the behavior you desire is to configure your web server to serve your actual content for requests to `alumni.example.com` and for all other `example.com` names just redirect (301) to the corresponding `alumni.example.com` url.

Comment: Thank you... I have done some tests and updated my OP... Do you have any idea?

Comment: @SoftTimur Good catch, I didn't think of your names under *alumni*